# How to increment a counter and not use the in-memory entity's current count value?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Say I have an entity that has a counter column.

If I want to increment the counter, there will be concurrency issues if I increment/decrement the in-memory version of the entity and then save as another request could have already incremented the counter and my in-memory representation has a stale value.

What options do I have nhibernate?

I know in RubyOnRails they have a special function that increments a counter like:

```
Entity.IncrementCounter("EntityName", "columnName", value => 1) // which means increment by 1
```

**Update**

Actually I guess I could use HQL for this right?
What about using criteria?

Answer (score 1):

When you say counter, do you mean like version?

NHibernate has a version column that already does this for you. See http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency

Comment: No I mean a couter, like:  User.SalesCount += 1 or product.Inventory += 1

Comment: You could apply similar tricks. Add the SalesCount field to the where clause and increment it as normal in your entity.

Comment: but is it using the in-memory value?  or incrementing what is in the database at the time of incrmeneting?

Comment: If you issued UPDATE Sales SET SalesCounter=2 WHERE Id=1 and SalesCounter=1, that solves your concurrency issue right? ... and you can do it in memory.

Comment: that's still considered 'in-memory'?  Looks more like a call pushed to the db server (which is what I want)